# Logistic regression - logloss values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When evaluating model performance of logistic regression, I was told that it is normal to use the logloss metric, as I am evaluating the probability of a given record to be 0 or 1 (Binary Classification).

Logloss would normally have varying values in the range 0-1 as I change input parameters.

In the context of a problem I am solving, I have this line of code

```
LR = LogisticRegression(C=rangeC[n-1], solver='liblinear').fit(X_train,y_train)
```

C is the inverse of regularization strength, a parameter to avoid over-fit for the current dataset. In this problem its values vary from 0.01 to 0.99

When I output the Logloss metric I get values way too far from the range [0-1]...

[image: Logloss vs C]

Is this normal to happen in sklearn lib? How can I avoid it?

**Edit: Problem solved.**

I forgot to mention the values I was passing to the logloss metric.

I was doing

```
log_loss(ytest, yhat)
```

ytest are the actual values, yhat the predicted values of the set.

It happens that the log_loss receives

```
log_loss(ytest, yhat_proba)
```

yhat_proba (in the context of Logistic Regression) is a 2-dimensional array with the probabilities of class 0 and 1 for each record.

Ex: [[0.41 0.59]...[0.6 0.4]].

Finally I got the desired chart:

[image: Logloss vs C]

Comment: logloss is not restricted to [0,1].

Comment: @BenReiniger logloss is restricted to the [0,1] interval in the context I was working (Logistic Regression - Binary Classification). Even by the chart we could see that something wasn't done correcty, it is supposed to output a logarithmic function which is a curve...